# Assign id to Sticky Notes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I give id as 0,1,2 etc. to sticky notes and get its id back on click event.Below is the fiddle code of sticky notes in which we can add multiple sticky notes I want to assign them an id as 0,1,2 etc. and get its id back when click on specific sticky note

```js
(function() {
    
      var markup =
        '<div class="box note background-gray">' +
        '<div class="box-header">' +
        '<a href="#" class="left add hidden">&plus;</a>' +
        '<a href="#" class="right remove hidden">&times;</a>' +
        '</div><textarea class="note-text"></textarea></div>';
    
      var spawn = function() {
        $("body").append(makeNote($(markup)));
      };
    
      var remove = function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      };
    
      var resizeTextArea = function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var spaceToGrab = 60;
        self.find('.note-text').height(self.height() - 45);
      };
    
      var hideButtons = function(element) {
        $(element).find("a").hide();
      };
    
      var showButtons = function(element) {
        $(element).find("a").show();
      };
    
      var save = function(id, value, position) {
        console.log(id); // position
        console.log(value);
        console.log(position);
      };
    
      var makeNote = function(element) {
        var $note = $(element);
        $note.resizable({
          handles: "se"
        });
        $note.draggable({
          handle: ".box-header"
        });
    
        $text = $note.find('textarea');
        $text.focusout(function(e) {
          save($(this).oid, $(this).val(), $(this).parent().position());
        });
        $note.click(function() {
          $(this).find('textarea').focus();
        });
    
        $note.mouseover(function() {
          showButtons(this);
        });
        $note.mouseout(function() {
          hideButtons(this);
        });
    
        $note.find(".add").click(spawn);
        $note.find(".remove").click(remove);
        $note.resize(resizeTextArea);
        hideButtons($note);
        return $note;
      };
    
      $(".note").each(function(i, e) {
        makeNote(e);
      });
    
      spawn();
    })();
```

```css
.box {
      min-width: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
      margin: 20px;
      display: block;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .note {
      /* box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset; */
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #888;
      background-color: lime;
    }

.box-header {
      min-height: 30px;
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
      text-align: right;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    .box-header a {
      display: block;
      margin: 4px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-size: 24px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT", "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #666;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .box-header a:link,
    .box-header a:visited {
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    }
    
    .box-header a:hover,
    .box-header a:active {
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .left {
      float: left;
    }
    
    .right {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .note-text {
      margin: 0;
      background: none;
      border: none;
      font-family: "Helvetica", "Arial", "sans-serif";
      font-size: 24px;
      width: 100%;
      font-style: italic;
      resize: none;
      overflow: auto;
      outline: none;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .background-gray {
      background: #ffffff;
      /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
      /* FF3.6+ */
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #e0e0e0));
      /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
      /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
      /* Opera 11.10+ */
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
      /* IE10+ */
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e0e0e0 100%);
      /* W3C */
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e0e0e0', GradientType=0);
      /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-lnH4vnCtlKU2LmD0ZW1dU7ohTTKrcKP50WA9fa350cE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[Sticky Notes](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cessor/Nutvt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You just have to count the already existing elements to calculate the id for the element which is going to be inserted.</strike>

```
$note.attr("id", $(".note.box").length + 1);
```

### [DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Nutvt/163/)

Since you are removing and adding elements dynamically, the right way to add `id` would be adding id to all the elements when you add an element newly.

```
$(".note.box").add($note).attr('id', function(i, id){ return i; });
```

But note that the ids won't be constant for the sticky notes.

If you wanna insert static ids, then you have to maintain a counter as @DBS mentioned in the comment below.

### [DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Nutvt/164/)

Comment: You might want to use a counter, since it appears notes can be removed. (Meaning the length value could give the same "ID" twice)

Comment: @JohnWick Clicking where?

Comment: clicking on notes as u can see  $note.click(function () {
            $(this).find('textarea').focus();
        });

Comment: Thanks, @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ur answer was what I wanted...do you know ckeditor my next query Is related to it

Comment: @JohnWick Nope. You can close this question by marking it accepted if you feel that my answer has resolved the query that you asked. And ask a new one with the details of ckeditor or whatever you want. So that you could more attention, not only me.